# Is it safe when reassign a map while multi tread are reading it?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I'm analysing big amount of log messages. about 10 log-analysis working thread need to get user information from this PlatformUserPool which is a single instance. and this pool I want it reload at 0 clock every day.cause reloading cost about 5 seconds,I read the records to a temp map in the first place,and then assign it to the real pool.

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PlatformUser.class);

private Map<String,PlatformUser> pool = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlatformUser>();
private PlatformUserDAO platformUserDAO = new PlatformUserDAO(MorphiaFactory.getMorphia(), MongoConnection.getClient());
private static final PlatformUserPool instance = new PlatformUserPool();

private PlatformUserPool(){}

public static PlatformUserPool getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public PlatformUser getPlatformUser(String userId){
    return pool.get(userId);
}

public void reload(){
    try {
        Iterator<PlatformUser> itr = platformUserDAO.find().iterator();

        Map<String, PlatformUser> tempPool = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlatformUser>();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            PlatformUser user = itr.next();
            if (user != null) {
                tempPool.put(user.getId(), user);
            }
        }

        pool = tempPool;

        LOG.info("reload PlatformUserPool successfully.");
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("error occur while reloading PlatformUserPool.",e);
    }
}

public void reloadDaily(){
    Date now = new Date();
    long time2EndOfDay = Utils.getEndOfDay(now).getTime() - now.getTime();

    //reload everyday 00:00AM
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reload();
        }
    },time2EndOfDay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1,TimeUnit.DAYS), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

So far so good .But, I still not so sure about it is thread safe or not. Any opinions will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading `pool` is not thread safe, as other threads could still see the stale value of `pool`.

To make sure that all threads see latest reference, you should use `synchronized` keyword. But if I understand correctly, `pool` is read by other threads and modified only inside `reload()`. If that is the case, you can simply use `volatile`:

```
private volatile Map<String,PlatformUser> pool = 
                new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlatformUser>();
```

This would avoid any lock contention and also provide read / write barrier.

Comment: yes,you are right.and,read old value of pool is totally ok for me.

Comment: If reading stale value is okay for you (which I doubt because other threads may never see updated `pool`) then you do not need these modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But,I don't have a clue about **other threads may never see updated pool**,the thread may use the old pool for seeking user once. but when they invoke the getPlatformUser again for another log.the pool will be a new fresh one.doesn't it?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed. When `reload()` is called it updates `pool` reference but other threads may be referring stale `pool` in their cache / register. To make sure that all threads see updated `pool` reference (from main memory), you need to declare it `volatile` or use synchronized access.

Comment: Visibility of `pool` is the main issue here. For more info you can refer this draft which I have just submitted for review.
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/25485?draftId=23210

Comment: I think you are right, although I don't really understand. Thank you again.